# ChartJS remove previous chart when making new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, chart.js

In the code below I am making a chartJS chart using database data, this is being done via a submit button which looks like this:

```
function showWhatSelected(str) {
$('#select2').hide();
$('#select3').hide();
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("select1").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("select1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../controller/teamleiderController.php?action=whatToShow&value="+ str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

After that the AJAX runs which makes the new chart when a change has been detected in the submit button:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "../controller/teamleiderController.php?action=select2JSON&value="+ str +"",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var label = ['aanwezig', 'afwezig'];
                var aanwezigheid = [];

                for(var i in data) {
                    aanwezigheid.push(data[i].aanwezig, data[i].afwezig, );
                }

                var chartdata = {
                    labels: label,
                    datasets : [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 65, 140, 0.8)', 'rgba(215, 165, 0, 0.8)'],
                            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                            hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 65, 140, 1)', 'rgba(215, 165, 0, 1)'],
                            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0)',
                            data: aanwezigheid
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var option = {
            };

                var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: chartdata,
                    options:option
                });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
}
```

My problem is that my chart is ghosting, it keeps showing previous data, is there any way I can fix this? I have tried .destroy() and .clear() but they both don't seem to work...

Comment: try this one $("#mycanvas").empty() in success function

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately...

Comment: it should work. can you please setup jsfiddle. where you place that above line?

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to use **`.destroy()`** method to remove any previous instance of chart before making a new one.

Perhaps, you were using the **`.destroy()`** method in an inappropriate manner, which made it non-effective.

Here­*'s* how you could properly remove / destroy any previous instance of chart, before creating a new one ...

```
var meta = barGraph && barGraph.data && barGraph.data.datasets[0]._meta;
for (let i in meta) {
   if (meta[i].controller) meta[i].controller.chart.destroy();
}
```

<sup>affix the above code before initiating your chart</sup>

***note:*** `barGraph` must be a global variable.

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var barGraph;

function init(str) {
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://istack.000webhostapp.com/json/" + str + ".json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         var label = ['aanwezig', 'afwezig'];
         var aanwezigheid = [];
         for (var i in data) {
            aanwezigheid.push(data[i].aanwezig, data[i].afwezig);
         }
         var chartdata = {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
               backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 65, 140, 0.8)', 'rgba(215, 165, 0, 0.8)'],
               borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
               hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 65, 140, 1)', 'rgba(215, 165, 0, 1)'],
               hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0)',
               data: aanwezigheid
            }]
         };
         var option = {responsive: false};
         
         // destroy previous chart
         var meta = barGraph && barGraph.data && barGraph.data.datasets[0]._meta;
         for (let i in meta) {
            if (meta[i].controller) meta[i].controller.chart.destroy();
         }
         
         // make new chart
         var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
         barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: chartdata,
            options: option
         });
      },
      error: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
}
```

```css
body{overflow:hidden}button{margin-left: 45px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="init('t1')">Dataset 1</button>
<button onclick="init('t2')">Dataset 2</button><br>
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="180"></canvas>
```